# How to recursively check for attributes in an object?

Tags: python, recursion, pygame, circuit

I've been working a circuit simulator, kind of like Minecraft's red-stone, but in 2d.

So far, I have power sources and wires. The power sources give power to the wire, which will later be used to power other components.

The problem I am facing is when the wire is disconnected from the source, it stays powered, because all of it's neighbors are powered.

Here is the issue represented in images:

Wire not connected to power

[image]

Wire is connected, and powered

[image]

Power removed, but wire is still active

[image]

Here is the update loop from the wire showing this:

```
def update(self):
    self.powered=False
    for b in blocks:
        #Find power sources/powered wires
        if not b.powered:
            continue
        adjacent = False
        if b.rect.collidepoint(self.rect.left,self.rect.top-5):
            adjacent = True
        if b.rect.collidepoint(self.rect.left,self.rect.bottom+5):
            adjacent = True
        if b.rect.collidepoint(self.rect.left-5,self.rect.top):
            adjacent = True
        if b.rect.collidepoint(self.rect.right+5,self.rect.top):
            adjacent = True
        if adjacent:
            self.powered = True
            break
    if not self.powered:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,0,0), self.rect, 0)
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (200,0,0), self.rect, 0)
```

I need the wires to be powered by other wires, but only if they are all connected to a source.. so I figured, if I can have each wire segment recursively check all the ones that it is connected to, to make sure it is connected to a power source, then I could achieve this. But I am not sure how to do this.

I tried using other variables inside of the wire object like `self.sourced` which represented if the wire was connected to a power source, but this resulted in only being able top power one wire. (even though when the power source was broken, the wire deactivated, so it kind of worked..)

Anyways, if anyone has know how to do this, please lend me your knowledge.

Here is the full source-code for reference:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

screen=pygame.display.set_mode((640,480))
blocks=[]

class PowerSource(object):
    def __init__(self,pos):
        self.posx=pos[0]
        self.posy=pos[1]
        self.rect=pygame.Rect(self.posx,self.posy,32,32)
        self.powered=True
    def update(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,0,0), self.rect, 0)
    def repos(self):
        pass
class Circuit(object):
    def __init__(self,pos):
        self.powered=False
        self.posx=pos[0]
        self.posy=pos[1]
        self.rect=pygame.Rect(self.posx,self.posy,32,32)
    def update(self):
        self.powered=False
        for b in blocks:
            if not b.powered:
                continue
            adjacent = False
            if b.rect.collidepoint(self.rect.left,self.rect.top-5):
                adjacent = True
            if b.rect.collidepoint(self.rect.left,self.rect.bottom+5):
                adjacent = True
            if b.rect.collidepoint(self.rect.left-5,self.rect.top):
                adjacent = True
            if b.rect.collidepoint(self.rect.right+5,self.rect.top):
                adjacent = True
            if adjacent:
                self.powered = True
                break
        if not self.powered:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,0,0), self.rect, 0)
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (200,0,0), self.rect, 0)
while True:
    place=1
    screen.fill((255,255,255))
    mse=pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    mse=((mse[0]/32)*32,(mse[1]/32)*32)
    pressed=pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    if pressed==(1,0,0):
        pressed='L'
    elif pressed==(0,0,1):
        pressed='R'
    for b in blocks:
        b.update()
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,0,0), (mse[0],mse[1],32,32), 2)
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type==QUIT:
            exit()
    key=pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if key[K_SPACE]:
        for b in blocks:
            if b.rect.collidepoint(mse):
                place=0
        if place==1:
            blocks.append(PowerSource(mse))
    if pressed=='L':
        for b in blocks:
            if b.rect.collidepoint(mse):
                place=0
        if place==1:
            blocks.append(Circuit(mse))

    elif pressed=='R':
        for b in blocks:
            if b.rect.collidepoint(mse):
                blocks.remove(b)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: This isn't part of your power issue, but I think you'll have a much easier time with everything if you start using a better data structure to hold your blocks. A grid would be one simple approach (let it hold `None` if a space is empty). Or, if that has too much memory overhead, you could use something cleverer, like a quadtree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're having trouble because of a few things.

You're probably going to want to have some sort of containing data structure (another class, not just a list) for your blocks, or have your blocks maintain an adjacency list. I think the latter is probably easier for understanding this question, though maybe the former is better for you since you need to be able to delete blocks (adjacency lists have a lot of bookkeeping). It's up to you, but I'm choosing adjacency lists since it's easier for me. :)

Once you have that down, you should write another method which serves as your recursive entry point. It can be pretty simple. You'll probably need to do something which keeps up with where you've visited; here I've done it as a set which is a parameter to the method, assuming an adjacency list called `neighbors`.

```
def is_connected_to_powered(self, visited=()):
    if self in visited:
        return False
    visited = set(visited)
    visited.add(self)
    for neighbor in self.neighbors:
        if neighbor.powered or neighbor.is_connected_to_powered(visited):
            return True
    return False
```

That answers this question, but I might also consider deriving Circuit and PowerSource from a common base class (Block?) since I suspect having proper OO will help you down the line.

Comment: How do I create an adjacency list? It looks like this kind of right? [_,_,_,_,0,0,_,0,_,0,_,_] With the _ being None, and the 0 being objects?

Comment: @SamTubb That's one way of doing it but maybe an easier way is to only store the neighbors in the list rather than `None`. For example, in the constructor, you initialize a member variable named `neighbors` to an empty list (or even a set). When that block gets a new neighbor, just do ``block.append(neighbor)`` (or ``add`` for sets). I would research Graph data structures to help your understanding, or consider building a class which helps you manage a 2D grid of blocks since you're building a block game (other people are suggesting a containing structure like this too).

Answer (score 2):

The short answer, from my experience, is to add a flag to the objects indicating whether or not they have been tested in the recursive algorithm. This is because you can have loops. So when you remove the power source, have it call a function to "check for source" for all blocks it is touching. Each block will set it's own flag stating "I've been checked" just prior to looking to see if it has a source as a neighbor. If it has a source as a neighbor it returns "yes I have a source". If not, then it checks to see if any neighbors have a source but only if they have not yet been flagged as having been checked. It will then see if any of the return values are "yes I have a source" and, if so, return "yes" If not, it returns "no" and shuts off.